# Inserting entries from remote posted XML

Tags: ee2, module, security, xml

I'm trying to post/update/delete entries in a channel by posting XML to a URL.

I've created a module with an action URL that does the processing and uses the Channel Entries API to manage the entries but this requires that I am logged in while I post the data.

My question is how can I post the data from a remote server without needing to be logged in?

Is it possible to authenticate a user by IP rather than logging in or emulate a users credentials from within the module?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just POST your data using a form and the SafeCracker module? Depending upon how you are submitting your data you could perhaps create the cookies for the login process? I am not sure how appropriate this would be, just a thought.

Comment: Or take a look at how SafeCracker handles this in the module code. It does allow for "guests" to post entries. You set up a member group with the permission would want, then set up a member whose ID you use for posting: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#allowing-guests-to-post-entries

Comment: @MediaGirl Thanks, I'd dismissed SafeCracked as I needed to do a lot of processing to the data but I'll have a look at that module code for the authentication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done this by securing the ACT id with a token of sorts, then before calling the API to import the data - I simply create a temporary user session for a superadmin.

Example:

```
function login_temporary_user()
{
    if( $this->EE->session->userdata['member_id'] == 0) 
    {
        $this->EE->session->create_new_session(1, TRUE);
        $this->EE->session->userdata['group_id']  = 1;
        $this->EE->session->userdata['can_edit_other_entries'] = 'y';
        $this->EE->session->userdata['can_assign_post_authors'] = 'y';
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it like so:

```
$this->login_temporary_user();
...
$this->EE->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry...
```

This will give your script the privelages it needs to perform insertions and updates if you require.

You could/should of course add additional security in your module to make sure the ACT is being triggered by a trusted source, but will leave that to you to work out. The session variables above should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I need. Can that code be changed to emulate a user group that is already setup to restrict access to a single channel?

Comment: Probably, you'd need to do a bit of debugging for trial/error. Take a look at the comments at the bottom of here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#9280

    $this->EE->api_channel_entries->errors

should give you an indication if permission errors are encountered. The docs are patchy on this to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

For an example of an existing approach to this you might want to take a look at how the [Entry API](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-api) module ($) handles this. This addon essentially provides CRUD api for channel entries via REST/XML-RPC (it also supports SOAP too if you happen to really hate yourself).

It does [use a member](http://reinos.nl/add-ons/entry-api/docs#Creating_Members_for_the_API) (which I's argue is a good thing, as you can then hook into the native permissions to restrict access to just the channels you need) & I'm not certain how it handles authentication, but for $45 it might well provide a leg up to get you to where you need to go.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using DataGrab for this?

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab

I know you can post and update entries via remote XML.

> Import data from RSS/ATOM feeds, CSV files and XML files. Other
>   datatypes can be added.
>
> Imports can be saved and re-run
>
> Entries can be updated if the source data changes — keep data
>   synchronized

And there is a setting to delete as well:

> Delete old entries
>
> If you check this, DataGrab will delete any entries in the channel
>   that have not been added or updated by this import. This can be useful
>   for maintaining an up-to-date product list, for example, but must be
>   used with care.

You can set saved imports to run via a template and or cron:

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support/details/running_imports_periodically_using_cron